# Organizing large javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've started to accumulate quite a few lines of Javascript code for a website. Everything has been in one file so far and that file is becoming impossible to maintain. If there is an error in one line, the entire file breaks.

I've tried splitting the code up into multiple files but there are some shared methods across objects like: `validateEmail(address)`.

Right now, I have my code organized into objects, like so:

```
var ProductPage = {
    addToCartBtn: "#add-to-cart",

    init: function() {
        ProductPage.initAddToCartPopup();
        ProductPage.initSidebar();
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

Then, I call `ProductPage.init()` on `$(document).ready`.

My issue is: when splitting `ProductPage` into a separate file as `ContactPage`, for example I cannot access `ContactPage.validateEmail()`. I believe this is because my code is wrapped in jQuery's:

```
(function ($) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone have insight on how they have organized large systems of Javascript? Also, I plan on doing optimization with putting all of this into one file and compressing it. So, any method which will benefit both maintainability and ease of optimization would be awesome.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org may be of some interest to you.

Comment: You might consider modules as well: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: I'd really recommend reading [Addy Osmani's wonderful article](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/). But in fact, any decent search on `Modular JavaScript` gives you several good results. For SO, however, it's too broad a topic; hence closure vote.

Comment: Combining Typescript and RequireJS can lead to wonderful application design (especially if you use an MVC framework that wants "classes"). There are a few issues with the TS compiler's speed and Require plugins, though, that take minor workarounds.

Comment: It should be noted that even if you break the script up, any error will halt the execution of all code from that point on, splitting it up in multiple files won't help at all for that issue.

Comment: Also, object literals are usually a good way to make code more modular, but your `addToCartBtn` property is just a string, generally you'd be better of to try and cache DOM nodes, and not just the string selector.

Comment: Thirdly, your jQuery function is not a DOM ready handler,  it's just an IIFE, and you are right, it creates it's own scope, and local variables in that scope can't be accessed from outside.

Comment: @phpete Tried `jsonp` ? Compose file as callback function , i.e.g., `mod({"ProductPage":{}})` (file names `mod-1` , or `product-mod`) .   Before `DOM` ready , before call to `$.getScript()` - `var mod = fn(mods) {}; var Pages = {}` (save fetched data until all `mods` fetched). Fetch each file with `$.getScript()` or `$.getJSON()` .  `var mods = ["mod-1.json", "mod-1.json"]` , `$.each(mods, fn(){})` (add to `Pages`). When complete , all fetched data held in , accessible at `Pages` object.

Answer (score 3):

`validateEmail` like methods are **functional** in my opinion. By functional I mean, `y = f(x)`. These functions are not changing the **state** but **returning an output** which are being **computed on the passed input**.

You might want to keep all this **utility functional methods** in a separate **module** and **tag it to a global namespace**. Make sure to load this(these) **utility module(s)** before utilizing them.

You can use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for **dependency management**.