# How to get instance of the "class" from JSON string?

Tags: javascript

Given that I have a class defined such as

```
(function () {
    function Dummy(){

        var toReturn ={
          myProp : "asdf",
          myFunc : myFunc
         }

         return toReturn;

        function myFunc(){};
    }    
})();
```

how does one get an instance of the same type after

```
var dummy = new Dummy();

JSON.stringify(dummy);
```

so that I have myFunc still available on the type.

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dummy))` returns  same shape of the object by not the same type.

NOTE: I am not asking about capability of JSON, but how do people deal with this in general. Do you hand roll your mapping mechanism so that after parsing from JSON you map it onto instance of the type, or if there is such functionality in some library, such as underscore.

I created a helper function that helps me do this, but would like to hear from others how do you deal with situation like this. As I put in comments, JSON comes over the wire, for which we have a type defined. To get the values from JSON in our type, we parse json, create instance of type and then apply map function below.

```
function map(fromObj, toObj) {
           Object.keys(fromObj)
                .forEach(function (key) {
                    if (typeof fromObj[key] != 'function') {
                        if (toObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                            if (typeof fromObj[key] !== 'object') {
                                toObj[key] = fromObj[key];
                            } else {
                                    map(fromObj[key], toObj[key]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: JSON cannot represent JavaScript functions, so the `myFunc` property cannot be serialized in a way that will cause it to become a function again when parsed.

Comment: @cdhowie I would assert that JSON *can* represent JavaScript functions (as strings representing the source, with caveats about scope), but that such a transformation is not standard or supported by the JSON.* methods..

Comment: @cdhowie: I know that, my question was not about how to do it with JSON, but how to do it in general.

Comment: @epitka In general, don't convert it to text. To write a custom text encoding of such, consider `Function.toString` *where* such yields a meaningful result and some form of `eval`. This will lose the lexical scope (e.g. closures) created by the original function. For other object types (eg. Dummy), define an applicable encoding of such (ie. also store the name of the "constructor function"), and defined rules of how to reconstitute them. Both of these transformations will quickly break down, but can be applied to specific cases.

Comment: @user2864740: My situation is that I am calling a service, that returns JSON, for which we have a type defined. So, in this simple scenario how do you map it.

Comment: @epitka Unless the goal is to make a "Universal Object Serializer" (of which I am sure there are some attempts), I would use a set of *transformation rules* as found in [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), for example. Basically, it walks the JSON object-graph (with default rules to restore an applicable object structure) but *also* lets one apply functions and transformations to the mapping process. Look at the `create` rule, which allows one to return arbitrary data - e.g. a custom object - for a matching source node.

Comment: @user2864740: No, I am not attempting anything that complicated. I created a mapping function, that is working pretty well so far, but I wanted to see what others are doing in situation like this.

Comment: In your example, you are not defining the class properly. Rather, you're just returning an object.

Comment: @epitka I have seen the data-transformation done on the client *with knowledge of the data/structure* in most cases - either through a mapping as KO Mapping, a statically-typed PO*O tree, or even a manual rebuilding. There are some projects (and additional schema-mappings) like [HydrateJS](http://nanodeath.github.io/HydrateJS/) or [Json.NET's TypeNameHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) which may be applicable with full control over the JSON itself - but this does impose a custom "meta schema" over the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Note, Not certain about requirement , if this similar to what posed at Question. If off-topic , please post comment , will withdraw.

Piece was originally composed for this Question [Organizing large javascript files [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369145/organizing-large-javascript-files#25369241) . With a `json` response , having "x" `type` of contents , could map returned object to new object , copying properties utilizing `$.extend()` .

Result would be new `object` having both properties and functions of returned data. At piece below, at completion of process , `$.Pages` begins as `function` , then type gets converted to `object` - though it could retain both `function` and `object` properties by including `|| {}` at definition stage.

Functions within returned `json` objects could be called within `.then()` callback ; see console at jsfiddle , object `init` functions.

At conclusion , `$.Pages` object has properties of returned `json` , including access to functions . Based on a `jsonp` - type processing flow.

Piece is "frame" of a processing approach ; could extend to include other functionality

```
$(function() {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    dfd.progress(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);

    });
  ProductPage = {
      name : "ProductPage",
    addToCartBtn: "#add-to-cart",
      initName : function() {return dfd.notify(this.name)},
    init: function() {
        this.initName();
        // ProductPage.initAddToCartPopup();
        // ProductPage.initSidebar();
    }
  };

  ContactPage = {
      name : "ContactPage",
      validateEmail : function (e) {return dfd.notify(e)},
      initName : function() {return dfd.notify(this.name)},
          init: function() {
        this.initName();
        // ProductPage.initAddToCartPopup();
        // ProductPage.initSidebar();
    }

  };

      var mods = function() {
          return {"ContactPage" : ContactPage
                  , "ProductPage" : ProductPage };
                            };
  $.Pages = function() {
    $.when(mods())
    .done(function(pages) {
      $.Pages = pages;
    });
      return $.Pages
  };
$.when($.Pages())
  .then(function() { 
      $.each($.Pages, function(k, v) {
       v.init();
      })

  });
  console.log($.Pages)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/60kv2439/1/ (see `console`)

basic approach

```
$p = {};
var queue = [];
var mods = ["dep1.json", "service1.json"];
var mod = function(m) {
queue.push(m);
if (queue.length === mods.length) {
  $.each(queue, function(k, v) {
    $p = $.extend(v, $p)
  })
}
};
$.each(mods, function(k, v) {
  $.getScript(v, function(script, status, jqxhr) {
    console.log($p)
  })

})
```